# Tirando Anúncio com o In App Purchase (IAP) Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Estou tentando usar o In App Purchase para remover os anúncios do meu app, porém os anúncios estão localizados em um View diferente de onde esta o código do IAP. Eu acho que estou removendo de um jeito não eficiente ou errado, pois o código esta quebrando na função de remover:

```
func removeallAds() {
    ViewController().bannerAd.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Esta me mostrando o seguinte erro:

Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Este é o meu View do meu IAP:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class IapViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    @IBOutlet weak var removeAds: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var restorePurchase: UIButton!


    @IBAction func removeAdsAct(sender: AnyObject) {
        for product in list{
            var prodId = product.productIdentifier
            if (prodId == "com.hazeApps.removeAds"){
                p = product
                buyProduct()
                break;
            }

        }
    }


    @IBAction func resPurchaseAct(sender: AnyObject) {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        removeAds.enabled = false


        //IAP Setup
        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()){
            println("IAP is up and running")
            var productId: NSSet = NSSet(object: "com.hazeApps.removeAds")
            var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productId)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        } else {
            println("enable IAPs")
        }


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var list = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()

    func buyProduct(){
        println("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
        var pay = SKPayment(product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)

            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
    }

    func removeallAds() {
        ViewController().bannerAd.removeFromSuperview()
    }


    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
        println("Product Request")
        var myProducts = response.products

        for product in myProducts{
            println("product added")
            println(product.productIdentifier)
            println(product.localizedTitle)
            println(product.localizedDescription)
            println(product.price)

            list.append(product as SKProduct)
        }

        removeAds.enabled = true
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
        println("Transaction restored")
        var purchasedItemIDS = []
        for transaction in queue.transactions{
            var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction

            let prodId = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

            switch prodId{
            case "com.hazeApps.removeAds":
                println("Remove Adds")
                removeallAds()
            default:
                println("IAP not setup")

            }
        }
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {

        println("add payment")

        for transaction: AnyObject in transactions{
            var trans = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction
            println(trans.error)

            switch trans.transactionState{

            case .Purchased:
                println("Unlock IAP here")
                println(p.productIdentifier)

                let productId = p.productIdentifier as String
                switch productId{
                    case "com.hazeApps.removeAds":
                        println("Remove Adds")
                        removeallAds()
                    default:
                        println("IAP not setup")

                }
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;

            case .Failed:
                println("buy error")
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;

            default:
                println("Default")
                break;


            }
        }
    }

    func finishTransaction(trans: SKPaymentTransaction){
        println("Finish Trans")
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("Removed Trans")
    }

}
```

Other thing, I have some line of code that handle in case of wireless connections to make the bannerAd hide, If the Ad is removed from superview it might get some error in this lines?

Comment: Já verificou se `bannerAd` não é nil nesse momento?

Comment: Se for é porque estou importando errado, porque não era para ser

Comment: De onde vem `bannerAd`?

Comment: Do ViewController, porém estou chamando ele no IadViewController

Comment: Como você está instanciando `IadViewController`? Storyboard?

Comment: Sim, é um View Controller como qualquer outro

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que quando `ViewController()` é chamado ele cria uma *nova* instância da classe `ViewController` e quando você tenta acessar `bannerAd` o programa quebra porque `bannerAd` é `nil`.

Para poder acessar os atributos na instância atual de `ViewController` você precisa passar alguma referência para a classe `IapViewController`.

Você pode fazer assim:

1. Declare uma variável na sua classe `IapViewController` para guardar a instância atual da `ViewController`

   ```
   // IapViewController
   var mainVC: ViewController!
   ...
   func removeallAds() {
      // se bannerAd for nil, removeFromSuperview() nem vai chegar a ser chamado
      mainVC.bannerAd?.removeFromSuperview()
   }
   ```
2. Dê um nome a segue que chama o `IapViewController` (vou usar "iapVcSegue") e adicione isso no `prepareForSegue` da classe `ViewController`:

   ```
   // prepareForSegue de ViewController
   if segue.identifier == "iapVcSegue" {
       var vc = segue.destinationViewController as IapViewController
       vc.mainVC = self;
   }
   ```

Essa técnica funciona mas talvez não seja o melhor modo. Como o anúncio vai ser removido permanentemente acho que seria mais interessante você usar `NSUserDefaults` ou adicionar um singleton global de configuração e no `viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear` de `ViewController` verificar e remover/não mostrar o banner.

Comment: Ta falando que ViewController? não tem um membro chamado bannerAd

Comment: @Skal Te perguntei antes de onde vinha bannerAd e você disse "do ViewController". De onde vem isso, então?

Comment: Vem do view controller sim ```class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate {
    
    //Definindo View Varaibles
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak internal var bannerAd: ADBannerView!```

Comment: Então é isso mesmo. Pode tentar essa solução que vai funcionar pra você.

Comment: Eu tentei, porém recebo dois erros, no ViewController: Use of undeclared type NewViewController. E no IapViewController:  ViewController? não tem um membro chamado bannerAd

Comment: Troca por IapViewContrler. Copiei do teste que fiz e esqueci de trocar. Editei a resposta.

Comment: No IapViewController ainda da o erro: ViewController? não tem um membro chamado bannerAd

Comment: Provavelmente porque o membro está declarado como internal. Você pode tirar o internal ou criar um método na classe ViewController que remova o elemento e chamar de IapViewController da mesma forma.

Comment: retirei o internal, mesmo erro.

Comment: Tente trocar `var mainVC: ViewController?` por  `var mainVC: ViewController!`.

Comment: Ok, agora o erro se foi, porém ainda esta aparecendo: Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Comment: Coloque um breakpoint no prepareForSegue e verifique se mainVC está sendo setado corretamente.

Comment: Sim esta setado corretamente